# Expandablelistview layout not fill parent

Tags: android, layout, textview, expandablelistview, fill-parent

I have an expandablelistview with 3 levels.
Here my layout files:

activity_main.xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ExpandableListView
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:id="@+id/ParentLevel"
         android:groupIndicator="@null"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </ExpandableListView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

load_deadlines_headers.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:background="#addfff">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Content1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

load_deadlines_children.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:background="#addfff">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Content2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Content3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="17sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

load_deadlines_subchildren.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:background="#addfff">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Content4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="60dp"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Item of second and Third level of my expandable list ( load_deadlines_children.xml and load_deadlines_subchildren.xml ) does not fill parent for layout_width.
I correctly specified

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

in code, but anyway it does not work.
I looking for an advice about this trouble.

Comment: Remove the `padding`?

Comment: No, nothing changes. For second and Third levels seems it's set wrap_content instead fill_parent. But code is correct.

Comment: for 3 levels my suggestion is use tree list view please check https://github.com/Polidea/tree-view-list-android

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft

Comment: Not the anser, just a hint: `fill_parent` is **deprecated**. Use `match_parent`

Comment: @arun
I do not understand your suggestion. my code already contain expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft val. I also try try to remove it, but the problem persist.